# Android Staggered Gridview Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gridlayout, staggered-gridview

have anyone done the same layout as fig. 1? i am currently using StaggeredGridLayoutManager but the result is fig 2. could anyone help me regarding this?

Ps tried using grid layout but it just copy the height of the largest height
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GridLayoutManager` instead of `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` for achieving same layout as fig. 1

`GridLayoutManager` creates the equal height grids.

```
val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
recyclerview.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
```

Comment: The problem is with gridlayout. It just copy the height of the item in the same row

Comment: Can you please add xml code and screenshot of output?

Comment: You were right. Gridlayout is really the answer. I just have to change my xml.lqyout